# combine two dicts with a user supplied expression

Tags: python

Let's say that I want to combine two dicts when a user supplied expression is true and the expression is allowed to reference fields of either dict.  Here's an example:

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 = {'m': 1, 'n': 3, 'o': 5}
dict3 = {'m': 2, 'n': 4, 'o': 6}

expression = "target['a'] == source['m']
```

desired result:

```
new_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'sub_dict': {'m': 1, 'n': 3, 'o': 5}}
```

The best solution I come up with is something like:

```
def combine(source, target, expression):
    try:
        if eval(expression):
            target['sub_dict'] = source
    except:
        pass
```

Short of writing a DSL for the conditional expression, are there better alternatives than this for allowing the dictionaries to be merged without the target (a separate module) having foreknowledge of the structure and content of the source and vice versa?

Comment: `except: pass` is a bad idea here.

Comment: Is the expression always just a comparison of values for a give key in each dictionary, or can it be some arbitrary Python code, like `sin(target["a"])**abs(target["c"]) <= 3-(source["m"] if source["n"] > 2 else source["o"])`? Just comparing a key from each dict could be easier to do safely than using `eval` on a complicated expression.

Comment: This might be stupid, but define "user supplied". It is actually textual input, or is it some module you're loading? If it's the latter, you can make it a function.

Comment: @Zirak user defined == a string representation of an expression that ideally evaluates to a boolean.

Comment: @Blckknght I believe it is going to be limited to value comparisons across the dictionaries.  The use case is basically a 3rd party module writer describing how their data is merged with a data tree from the core application.  The main application does the merging.

Comment: It can be really dangerous to allow "(untrusted) user-supplied expressions" to be eval'd (see here: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). Is it strictly necessary to have this level of flexibility, or could you have a set of pre-generated functions to chose from instead?

Comment: @TravisD. I had a basic sense of the danger, but the link you provided was very enlightening.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to compare specified values between the dictionaries, you should be able to avoid `eval` by specifying the keys into each `dict`, rather than a full expression.

```
def combine(source, target, source_key, target_key):
    try:
        if source[source_key] == target[target_key]:
            target['sub_dict'] = source
    except KeyError:
        # do something here?
        pass
```

Comment: I may have oversimplified the intended question and misled you with my response to the comment.  It is possible that the comparison is against more than one key of the dicts, or even that one of them has a key.  In other words, it could be a compound boolean expression.